# Extract JSON object properties into new array with Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a over 100+ JSON objects with this format:

```
{
"grants":[
{
    "grant":0,
    "ID": "EP/E027261/1",
    "Title": "Semiconductor Research at the Materials-Device Interface",
    "PIID": "6674",
    "Scheme": "Platform Grants",
    "StartDate": "01/05/2007",
    "EndDate": "31/10/2012",
    "Value": "800579"
}, ... more grants
```

I want to be able to grab EndDate and Value into a new array. Like the following output.

```
"extractedGrants":[
{
    "EndDate": "31/10/2012",
    "Value": "800579"
}, ... more extracted objects with EndDate and Value properties.
```

I believe the correct approach is to use array.map(function (a) {}); but I cannot get the code right inside the function.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a destruction of the object and a new object for the result array.

```js
var object = { grants: [{ grant: 0, ID: "EP/E027261/1", Title: "Semiconductor Research at the Materials-Device Interface", PIID: "6674", Scheme: "Platform Grants", StartDate: "01/05/2007", EndDate: "31/10/2012", Value: "800579" }] },
    result = object.grants.map(({ EndDate, Value }) => ({ EndDate, Value }));

console.log(result);
```

ES5

```js
var object = { grants: [{ grant: 0, ID: "EP/E027261/1", Title: "Semiconductor Research at the Materials-Device Interface", PIID: "6674", Scheme: "Platform Grants", StartDate: "01/05/2007", EndDate: "31/10/2012", Value: "800579" }] },
    result = object.grants.map(function (a) {
        return { EndDate: a.EndDate, Value: a.Value };
    });

console.log(result);
```